# How exactly to act on a confirmation dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog

New to Android... I understand Dialogs are asynchronous. But I really can't get my head around the flow for confirming an action. Can someone please explain the flow?

I want to save a file on the sdcard. The Activity prompts the used for the filename. Then it checks to see if the file exists. If it exists, it needs to prompt the user to confirm if they want to overwrite it. Then it proceeds to erase and write the file.

I know you can't hold execution waiting for the response. How then would this common flow work in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% it is what you are looking for, but here is a link to the Android documentation explaining how we should display Confirmation and Acknowledgement popups using the "Android standard way":

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact flow, I suppose it would depend on how the application was written. I would check for the file if it existed call the dialog windows then if the Ok/Yes/Confirm is pressed overwrite the file.
[Dialogs | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) - Has an excellent code example

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES! AKA Overwrite your file.
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog AKA do nothing
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

I know it's slightly silly example but basically check for the file (if exist) > Call Dialog (if yes)> Overwrite.

Comment: Yes... The Dialog part is easy. But how do you stick that in the middle of a program flow if you can't wait for a response? i.e. it's asynchronous.

Comment: I mean... I can hack together a convoluted flow. But I was hoping for something more elegant. There must be a "right way".